# Trying to build multiple image upload to Firebase: 2 Errors in SWIFT 4, FIREBASE 5.0.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, error-handling

I am making a project very similiar to Instagram's multiple image post feature, and I have 2 errors that are connected to each other in my capturePhotoController because of my ImageUploadManager. The errors are:

Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'ImageUploadManager.Type'
Type 'ImageUploadManager?' has no member 'uploadImage'

It is happening in this view controller: *The errors are marked with a comment

```
import UIKit

class takePicViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
 // Error       ImageUploadManager = ImageUploadManager()
 // Error        ImageUploadManager?.uploadImage(userPickedImage, progressBlock: { (percentage) in
                print(percentage)
            }, completionBlock: { (fileURL, errorMessage) in
                 print(fileURL)
                print(errorMessage)
            })

            PhotoArray.sharedInstance.photosArray.append(userPickedImage)  //append converted data in array

            imageView.image = userPickedImage

        }

        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func cameraButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}
```

Here is the code for the ImageUploadManager:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import Firebase

struct Constants {

    struct Car {
        static let imagesFolder: String = "carImages"
    }

}

class ImageUploadManager: NSObject {

    func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, /**/ progressBlock: @escaping (_ percentage: Double) -> Void, /**/ completionBlock: @escaping (_ url: String?, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

        let data = Data()

        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageRef = storage.reference()

        let imageName = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg"
        let imagesReference = storageRef.child(Constants.Car.imagesFolder).child(imageName)

        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
            let metadata = storageRef.child("image/jpg")


            let uploadTask = metadata.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                guard let metadata = metadata else {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                    return
                }

                storageRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                    guard let downloadURL = url else {
                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                        return
                    }
                }
            }

            uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
                guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                    return
                }

                let percentage = (Double(progress.completedUnitCount) / Double(progress.totalUnitCount)) * 100
                progressBlock(percentage)

            })
        } else {
            completionBlock(nil, "Image could not be converted to Data.")
        }

        }

}
```

Comment: this line doesn't make a lot of sense: 
`ImageUploadManager = ImageUploadManager()`.
Left side should be a variable name, you are attributing your object to the class name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the commented code:
`// Error       ImageUploadManager = ImageUploadManager()`
your declaration of `ImageUploadManager`? if so that is totally wrong. It should be declared as below:

```
if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    let imageUploadManager = ImageUploadManager()
    imageUploadManager.uploadImage(userPickedImage, prog.....
```

Reading your `ImageUploadManager` it looks like it's an stateless object and you can declare your function as a `class` function.

```
`class func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage`......`
```

You can then call it:

```
if let userPickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
    ImageUploadManager.uploadImage(userPickedImage, prog.....
```

Comment: I used your solution and have now gotten this error: Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type 'ImageUploadManager' whitch happens in the line "imageUploadManager?.uploadImage(userPickedImage, ......" of the first solution code you gave. Would you like to see the updated code with your anwser or have enough info from this comment?

Comment: @StackOverBlow Updated the answer. I suggest read more about swift at https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/

Comment: Well, actually I made some changes to the code I implemented from your answer and its seems to work. Thanks!